# NFS mount issues on orangepizero3 ubuntu client

Tags: mount, 22.04, nfs

I have a NFS server running with a valid export.conf, 3 of 4 clients on the network are able to connect to this server without issue and can read / write.

the forth client (orangepizero3) is the problem. When i try to mount the NFS directory i get the follow error

```
machs@orangepizero3:~$ sudo mount -t nfs  192.168.0.131:/media/smilingBuddha /media/smilingBuddha -vvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 15 13:35:23 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.0.131,clientaddr=192.168.0.246'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol error
mount.nfs: Protocol error
```

I've tried a few different incantations of the mount command specifying various NFS options, which ultimately fails after timing out.

```
machs@orangepizero3:~$ sudo mount -t nfs -o mountvers=3 electricsheep:/media/smilingBuddha /media/smilingBuddha -vvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 15 13:43:12 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'mountvers=3,addr=192.168.0.131'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.131 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.131 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 50411
mount.nfs: mount(2): Input/output error
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Further confusing things is that I can mount a NFS share from a older NAS box on orangepizero3 without issues )

```
machs@orangepizero3:~$ sudo mount /media/pillarOfAutumn -vvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Nov 15 13:36:56 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,intr,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.0.77,clientaddr=192.168.0.246'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,intr,vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.0.77,clientaddr=192.168.0.246'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,intr,vers=4,addr=192.168.0.77,clientaddr=192.168.0.246'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,intr,addr=192.168.0.77'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.77 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.77 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 46905
```

This succeeds and I can access that NFS directory!

The only thing i can think of is that orangepizero3 is running an old-ish kernel, which is nessecary since it the 6.x kernel did not work with the onboard wifi.

client

```
machs@orangepizero3:~$ showmount -e electricsheep
Export list for electricsheep:
/media/smilingBuddha 192.168.0.0/24


machs@orangepizero3:~$ rpcinfo -p electricsheep | grep nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs

machs@orangepizero3:~$ uname -a
Linux orangepizero3 5.4.125 #1.0.0 SMP Fri Jun 30 11:59:12 CST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

server

```
machs@electricSheep:~$ uname -a
Linux electricSheep 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

machs@electricSheep:~$ cat /etc/exports 
/media/smilingBuddha  192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I haven't been able to resolve with the normal method of googling the hell out of the error codes. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you